# Jenkins Pipeline based on groovy : unable to push into git => Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, push, jenkins-pipeline

**Jenkins Context**

Jenkins version : version 2.23
 
I am trying to make a git push from a jenkins pipeline using a groovy script.
The goal is to create a tag in a stage and push it remotely on my git repo.

What is going wrong with my pipeline job configuration (cf below)?

**Problem**

I have an account with credentialsId that runs perfectly for the fetch and clone.
But I get the following error when I try to push my tags.

> git push ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git --tags
>   Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

**Credentials / SSH**

Public key is correctly added into my git/gerrit server

The account has "ALLOW" rights on gerrit :

Reference: refs/tags/*

- Create Reference
- Forge Author Identity
- Forge Committer Identity
- Push
- Push Annotated Tag
- Push Signed Tag

**Jenkins Pipeline : groovy script**

---

```
node {
    echo "=================="
    string workspace=pwd()
    sh ('ls -al $workspace')

    String credentialsId="aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee"
    String  gitRepo="ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git"

    // stage
    stage "Test Tag Push"

    git credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", url: "${gitRepo}"


    println "cmd = git tag "
    sh(script: 'git tag')

    tagName="MyTag"

    sh(script: "git tag -d $tagName")
    sh(script: "git tag $tagName")
    sh(script: 'git tag')
    println "git repo : ${gitRepo}"
    sh('git push ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git --tags')
}
```

---

**Console Output**

```
> Entering stage Test Tag Push
Proceeding
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials aacloud user for gerrit connection
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 20fc371cf27bb57049e75a040f00986ab6a71473 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 20fc371cf27bb57049e75a040f00986ab6a71473
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 20fc371cf27bb57049e75a040f00986ab6a71473
 > git rev-list 20fc371cf27bb57049e75a040f00986ab6a71473 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
cmd = git tag 
[Pipeline] sh
[cockpit-pipeline-test-TC] Running shell script
+ git tag
MyTag
Tag001
tc001
tc002
[Pipeline] sh
[cockpit-pipeline-test-TC] Running shell script
+ git tag -d MyTag
Deleted tag 'MyTag' (was 20fc371)
[Pipeline] sh
[cockpit-pipeline-test-TC] Running shell script
+ git tag MyTag
[Pipeline] sh
[cockpit-pipeline-test-TC] Running shell script
+ git tag
MyTag
Tag001
tc001
tc002
[Pipeline] echo
git repo : ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git
[Pipeline] sh
[cockpit-pipeline-test-TC] Running shell script
+ git push ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git --tags
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Run git push as Jenkins user
..."su - jenkins -c"

Answer (score 7):

Git credentials are valid only for the `git` step (i.e. fetching the repository). You need to wrap your `sh` step with `sshagent`:

```
sshagent(credentialsId) {
    sh('git push ssh://git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git --tags')
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me... I always get a "Host key verification failed".
Even when I do a `ssh-keyscan` and put it into `~/.ssh/known_hosts` it does not work. Any ideas why this could still happen?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot Jil, that is the trick !!!
It works perfectly with sshagent

I would add it is also necessecary to add the account in the repository parameter

`gitRepo="ssh://MyAccount@git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git"`

Complete solution is

```
    node {
      String credentialsId="aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee"
      String gitLogin="MyAccount"
      String gitRepo="ssh://${gitLogin}@git.server:29418/AA/myrepo.git"
      stage "Test Tag Push"
      git credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", url: "${gitRepo}"   
      tagName="MyTag"    
      sh(script: "git tag $tagName")
      sshagent([credentialsId]) {
        sh(script: 'git push --tags')
      }
    }
```

Comment: Simplifications:  `git credentialsId: credentialsId, url: gitRepo` and `sh 'git push --tags'`

Comment: Also, it's not recommended to do `git push --tags`, because that will push all tags that happen to be created by accident. This is less likely to happen in a Jenkinsfile, but still... it's better to explicitly say what you want done: `sh "git push origin tag ${tagName}"` (the `tag` keyword is refspec syntax specific to `git push`).